# Kubectl command giving continuous connection errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, runtime-error, amazon-iam, kubectl

I am running the command:

```
kubectl describe -A pvc | grep -E "^Name:.*$|^Namespace:.*$|^Mounted By:.*$" | grep -B 2 "<none>" | grep -E "^Name:.*$|^Namespace:.*$" | cut -f2 -d: | paste -d " " - - | xargs -n2 bash -c 'kubectl -n ${1} delete pvc ${0}'
```

and when I run it.. it gives me a continuous errors of:

```
constructing many client instances from the same exec auth config can cause performance problems during cert rotation and can exhaust available network connections; clients constructed calling "heptio-authenticator-aws"
constructing many client instances from the same exec auth config can cause performance problems during cert rotation and can exhaust available network connections; clients constructed calling "heptio-authenticator-aws"
constructing many client instances from the same exec auth config can cause performance problems during cert rotation and can exhaust available network connections; clients constructed calling "heptio-authenticator-aws"
constructing many client instances from the same exec auth config can cause performance problems during cert rotation and can exhaust available network connections; clients constructed calling "heptio-authenticator-aws"
constructing many client instances from the same exec auth config can cause performance problems during cert rotation and can exhaust available network connections; clients constructed calling "heptio-authenticator-aws"
constructing many client instances from the same exec auth config can cause performance problems during cert rotation and can exhaust available network connections; clients constructed calling "heptio-authenticator-aws"
constructing many client instances from the same exec auth config can cause performance problems during cert rotation and can exhaust available network connections; clients constructed calling "heptio-authenticator-aws"
```

- I am using it to delete my unmounted kubernetes pvc's.. how do I fix the error?
- It just outputs this error and no pvc is deleted.

Comment: do you really need to do the deletions in parallel? you probably shouldn't be using xargs here.

Comment: what do u mean parallel? I just want to delete them.. do u know how to fix the problem? @jordanm

Comment: How many PVC are there to be deleted? It might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/91913)

Comment: @MariuszK. many.. around 800 ish

Comment: That might cause the issue as mentioned in the github issue linked above. Can you try to delete PVCs  per namespace for example? To lower the number of objects to be deleted.

Comment: @MariuszK. how do I do that? can u help?